# Locally hosted fonts breaking CSP rule

Tags: content-security-policy, typekit

I'm setting up `Content-Security-Policy` headers in `Nginx` and I am stuck at getting the locally hosted `Typekit` fonts to work.

I'm using the following script for hosting `Typekit` fonts locally and the result has been very good with good load times and no FOUT: https://github.com/morris/typekit-cache

But now the problem is setting up CSP to pass these fonts. I tried localStorage but it didn't work.

These are the errors I'm getting:

> [Report Only] Refused to load the font
>   'data:font/opentype;base64,d09GMgABAAAAAFb0ABQAAAAAskgAAFaDAAIAAAAAAAAAAAAAA…bJbjfY7U6T320POPp5HLprLxRlPwIJqShhBB1pRCUKkQmIKRpGoiON1kre7lGR0Z4h5ENMAQAA'
>   because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "font-src 'self'
>
> [Report Only] Refused to load the font
>   'data:application/font-woff;base64,d09GRgABAAAAABwUAA4AAAAAKHQAAQAAAAAAAAAAA…NfJJTVolXlnco7lXdLiWW32CnmmMrFlnJ5aXLN8srxynGxmBgfv9d+AQ8KdggAAAABVwJMPAAA'
>   because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "font-src 'self'

*(I removed the domains listed for the font-src policies).*

Thank you

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can see its creating the font-src as `data` when it loads them in. That is base64 encoded versions of the font rather than links to the fonts themselves.

So just change `font-src 'self';` to `font-src 'self' data: ;` and it should work fine.

Comment: Thank you that takes care of the problem perfectly!